# Aggregate function. Sequence of steps

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

Here is the simple task, and the solution, which uses aggregate function. I have a general idea of how to use this function (for example: counting sum of elements, multiplying numbers). However I can not figure out the exact sequence of steps in this solution.

We have array, which contains 4 distinct integer values and string with  appearances of the array's indexes.

```
int[] nums = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
string str = "123214";
```

We need to count number of appearances of each index, multiply by a corresponding value and then sum this all up, so that the answer would be 13.

Here is the solution, using aggregate function:

```
 str.Aggregate(0, (i, c) => i + nums[c - '1']);
```

What is the sequence of steps that this function performs?

Comment: It is not clear for me, what you are asking, but you can look at `Aggregate` [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/82b209add5c21465.html).

Comment: What is the problem you have? Aggregate function is applied to each element in the sequence (char in the string) summing correspondent integers for each char(index). If you want to have LINQ that operates in a way like you described (counting characters), you can try`str.GroupBy(ch => ch)
                    .Select(group =>
                        nums[group.Key - '1'] * group.Count())
                    .Sum()`. Both solutions are equivalent. Just the first one is more simple, while the second directly reflects the desired algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can *solve* this using eq. reasoning:

```
str.Aggregate(0, (i, c) => i + nums[c - '1'])
= "123214".Aggregate(0,(i,c) => i+nums[c-'1'])
(i := 0, c := '1' => 0+nums['1'-'1'] = 0+nums[0]=0+1 = 1)
= "23214".Aggregate(1, ...)
(i := 1, c := '2' => 1+nums[1]=1+2=3)
= "3214".Aggregate(3, ...)
(i := 3, c:='3' => 3+nums[2]=3+3=6)
= "214".Aggregate(6,...)
(i:=6, c:='2' => 6+nums[1]=6+2=8)
= "14".Aggregate(8,...)
(i:=8,c:='1' => 8+nums[0]=8+1=9)
= "4".Aggregate(9,...)
(i:=9,c:='4' => 9+nums[3]=9+4=13)
= "".Aggregate(13,...)
= 13
```

I hope this helps

To really learn things like this I would encourage you to look into functional programming (look for *fold*s) - basically the first parameter in `Aggregate` is a **state** that gets passed around and second parameter is a **function** taking the *old state and the next element in the enumeration* (in this case the next character in your string) and has to produce a *new state*. So in your case the *state* is just a number and you calculate it by adding up the old state with a lookup from your `nums` array based on the numeric value of your character (as index).